# .htaccess rewrite URL starting / redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am looking for regular expression which would match a pattern

```
 /catalogue/name-of-the-product-p1-1-1.php
```

Or

```
 /catalogue/name-of-the-product-p1.php
```

And redirect to:

```
/name-of-the-product
```

The code I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/catalogue/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-p(.+)\.php /$1 [R=301]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You used the tag [tag:.htaccess] but note that `^/` will never match in a .htaccess file, as you only have the current partial path left.

Comment: Both your answers are correct when I test them on regexr.com but when I placed any of this rules in .htaccess there is no redirect and the site is showing 404 page instead?

Comment: Look in your server log files for error messages.
It would be better to place this rewrite in your apache configuration file. 
You need to precede it with `RewriteEngine on`. It will work in an .htaccess only at
the top of your document root, if you also add `Options +FileInfo`, and only if you start the pattern with either "^catalogue" or "^/?catalogue" as in 
one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^/?catalogue/([A-Za-z0-9-]+?)-p([0-9]+)([^.]*)\.php$ /$1 [R]
```

The regex pattern "^/?catalogue/([A-Za-z0-9-]+?)-p([0-9]+)([^.]*).php$" Can match
both Request uris **/catalogue/name-of-the-product-p1-1-1.php** Or **/catalogue/name-of-the-product-p1.php** it first matchs "catalogue" litearly, and then "([A-Za-z0-9-]+?)" matchs  "name-of-the-product" and saves the value as $1 for reuse in Rewrite target.

Comment: Can you explain briefly why this would fit the scenario described?

Comment: Applied this in magento .htaccess as the old site was migrated into it. I also added [R=301,L] R=301 – to let google know that it is permanent move / change and L – so it can stop looking for more rewrites matches. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^/catalogue/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-p[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*\.php
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!